# Testing Catch Statements of a NFE

Tags: java, syntax-error

Alright so I am an intro student in a programming class and I am trying to test a catch statement of a NFE.  I don't know how to format the code properly, but here it is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Geo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Name?");
            String name = inp.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Number?");
            double num = inp.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Integer?");
            int num2 = inp.nextInt();
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage error");
        }
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(num2);   
    }

}
```

It keeps saying the variables, name, num, and num2 are undefined.  What am I doing wrong here, because I was looking back at an old lab and that is exactly how I had done it before. Any hints?

Now I fixed it so the code looks like this

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        try {
            Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Name?");
            String name = inp.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Number?");
            double num = inp.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Integer?");
            int num2 = inp.nextInt();
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(num);
            System.out.println(num2);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage error");
        }

    }
```

but the catch isnt running. How does that get fixed. Like I want it run the try completely, but if something is wrong it keeps running, then out of try, then catches the issue.

Comment: You need to define those variables outside of the `try/catch` scope.

Comment: Or move the println statements inside the try block so that they are in the same scope..

Comment: okay, could I also just get rid of the try?

Comment: @Jack Not if you want to catch the NFE.

Comment: I think this question should be asked on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so for every catch you need a try? Im new to this but I know that for if's dont need else's, so why cant it be the same thing here

Comment: also, after I fixed it, the catch part isnt running if I type in a non int/double for the input. Any tips.

Comment: Just change NumberFormatException to Exception.

Comment: never learned Exception, but that will do it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initial variables on top of try/catch.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = null;
    double num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    try {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name?");
        name = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Number?");
        num = inp.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Integer?");
        num2 = inp.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Usage error");
    }
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(num2);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name?");
        String name = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Number?");
        double num = inp.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Integer?");
        int num2 = inp.nextInt();

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(num2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Usage error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables you are referring to are defined in the `try` block and are therefore visible only in it, while you are trying to read them outside of the `try` block.

You can either do the printing in the `try` block, or define the variables in `main` function.